# Counting the left cosets of a group under a particular condition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to prove the following equality without success*:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H\le G$ a subgroup. Denote by [g] the conjugacy class of $g\in G$ and by $G_g$ the centralizer of $g\in G$ in $G$. Then
>   $$
> |{kH\in G/H\ :\ k^{-1}gk\in H}|\ =\ |G_g|\cdot\frac{|[g]\cap H|}{|H|}
> $$

I tried to use the following:

- $|G_g|=\frac{|G|}{|[g]|}$
- Burnside's lemma
- Lagrange theorem
- ...

without find a solution.

Thx for help.

(*) the equality occurs in Sunada's paper “*Riemannian coverings and isospectral manifolds*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the map $\{k \in G : k^{-1}gk \in H\} \rightarrow [g] \cap H, k \mapsto k^{-1}gk $ is surjective and its fibres are cosets of $G_g$, hence we have

$$ \left|\{k \in G : k^{-1}gk \in H\}\right| = \left|G_g\right| \; \left|[g] \cap H\right|. $$

But of course we also have 
$$\left|\{k \in G : k^{-1}gk \in H\}\right| =\left|H\right| \; \left|\{kH \in G/H : k^{-1}gk \in H\}\right|$$
and putting both equations together gives the result.

Comment: by denoting your first map $\phi$: when you says that the fibres are cosets of $G_g$ are you meaning that $|G_g|=|\phi^{-1}(h)|,\ h\in[g]\cap H$?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that for any $h = k^{-1}gk \in [g] \cap H$, we have $\varphi^{-1}(\{h\}) = G_gk$. In particular, we have $|\varphi^{-1}(\{h\})| = |G_g|$.

Comment: ok! now all is clear. thx!